# Zoom meeting sdk v5.16.1.16439 && v5.16.2 crashing on initializing in Android

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

Android app is crashing on initializing zoom meeting sdk v5.16.1 and 5.16.2 both.
Initially I was using meeting sdk v5.13.1 and app was working fine but as I tried upgrading the version,
app is crashing.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imarticus.staging/com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.ZmConfActivity}:
This file should be inside zoom meeting sdk , but not inflating this class.
Kindly check the logs attached below inside Addtional Context.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.imarticus.staging/com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.ZmConfActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/activity_foldable_conf: Binary XML file line #42 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/activity_foldable_conf: Error inflating class com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmMobileMainControlLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/activity_foldable_conf: Binary XML file line #42 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/activity_foldable_conf: Error inflating class com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmMobileMainControlLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/activity_foldable_conf: Error inflating class com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmMobileMainControlLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.ZmConfActivity.onCreate(ZmConfActivity.java:14)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #406 in com.imarticus.staging:layout/zm_conf_control_view_panel: For input string: “16.0dip”
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “16.0dip”
at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:485)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:476)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.(ConstraintLayout.java:3283)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1934)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:486)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1129)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:28489)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmBaseMainControlLayout.a(ZmBaseMainControlLayout.java:13)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmBaseMainControlLayout.(ZmBaseMainControlLayout.java:45)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmBaseMainControlLayout.(ZmBaseMainControlLayout.java:2)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.view.ZmMobileMainControlLayout.(ZmMobileMainControlLayout.java:2)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
at com.zipow.videobox.conference.ui.ZmConfActivity.onCreate(ZmConfActivity.java:14)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

Initialized meeting sdk and app was crashed in version 5.16.1 && 5.16.2.
```